# Edge keep showing pdf file as Base64 String

Tags: javascript, pdf, base64, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to show pdf file on web browser by converting encoded Base64 String to pdf form in Javascript.
Chrome shows the pdf correctly but Edge keep showing Base64 string, not pdf form.
Anybody knows how to solve this?

```
function showPdf(pdf){
        let pdfWindow = window.open("");
        pdfWindow.document.write(
                                  "<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/pdf;base64, "
                                  +encodeURI(pdfData)+"'></iframe>"
                                );    

}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on my development system in Chrome, Firefox or Edge using your code and a known good base64-encoded PDF document. Could your original PDF file be the problem?

Comment: I converted the pdf file to base64 format through an online tool, and using your code, it can work normally in ms Edge (Version 91.0.864.71) (Official build) (64-bit). Can you provide more details so that we can reproduce your problem? Thank you for understanding.